# NullPointerException when injecting to PedSource with a level created in code

Tags: anylogic

I'm using the pedestrian library. At this point the model is creating a number of rectangular walls that represent shelf mods, and the pedestrians enter and move to a point and then exit.

The walls are created at startup from a database table of x, y coordinates and sizes.

```
Level level = new Level(this, "mylevel", SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, 0);

List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(sheet1)
    .list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
    int xPos = row.get(sheet1.graphics_pivot_point_x);
    int yPos = row.get(sheet1.graphics_pivot_point_y);
    int shapeWidth = row.get(sheet1.graphics_width);
    int shapeHeight = row.get(sheet1.graphics_height);
    //String aislename = row.get(sheet1.aisle);

    RectangularWall rw = new RectangularWall();
    rw.setSize(shapeWidth, shapeHeight);
    rw.setPos(xPos, yPos, 0);
    rw.setVisible(true);
    rw.setOwner(this);
    
    level.add(rw);
    
}

level.initialize();

presentation.add(level);
```

I currently have a PedSource, a PedGoTo, and a sink. There is also a button with pedSource.inject() as the action to test how they move around the walls.

however, when I click the button I get the following error:

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.BoundingRectangle.getMinX(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.modules.level_system.LevelDataBuilder.d(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.modules.level_system.LevelDataBuilder.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.modules.level_system.LevelDataStorage.a(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1133)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.modules.level_system.LevelDataStorage.getLevelData(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.an.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.PedLevel_xjal.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.PedSettings.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.PedEnter.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.PedEnter.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.PedEnter.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.PedEnter.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.pedestrian.PedEnter$2.onEnter(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay$9.onEnter(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.receiveImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.action(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.AsynchronousExecutor_xjal$a.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler$n.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.cl(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$n.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I draw a single rectangular wall and then run the same code, the pedestrians enter the block and follow expected behaviour.

So this leads me to there being an issue with my code and it's like the pedSource block and objects I create are not in the same level or something similar.

i have been through all the documentation and searched but I can't find the solution or see where I have gone wrong. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction, please and thank you.

Comment: can you see the layout stuff you created programmatically, before you click the button? If not, ensure you actually create your stuff properly first

Comment: yes, the walls are displayed. When I draw a node and then start the model the pedestrians appear and do move as intended, but they walk through the walls that are created programmatically

Comment: you may need to add the wall to the level as well, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve the problem

1. Change the name of the default level to levelX.
2. create a variable called myLevel in main or where your walls are being built... the initial value of this variable will be a function that returns a value of type Level, in which you will write the code you are using
3. in your code, instead of using

   Level level = new Level(this, "mylevel", SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, 0);

do

```
Level level = levelX;
```

you don't need these lines anymore

```
level.initialize();

presentation.add(level);
```

Instead, you just do return level at the end of it, since everything will be in a function that returns that... so like this:

```
Level level = levelX;

List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(sheet1)
    .list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
    int xPos = row.get(sheet1.graphics_pivot_point_x);
    int yPos = row.get(sheet1.graphics_pivot_point_y);
    int shapeWidth = row.get(sheet1.graphics_width);
    int shapeHeight = row.get(sheet1.graphics_height);
    //String aislename = row.get(sheet1.aisle);

    RectangularWall rw = new RectangularWall();
    rw.setSize(shapeWidth, shapeHeight);
    rw.setPos(xPos, yPos, 0);
    rw.setVisible(true);
    rw.setOwner(this);
    
    level.add(rw);
    
}

return level;
```

Didn't test, but hopefully it will work out

Comment: that works, thank you very much